# Access a control inside a usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I have a DropDownList inside a usercontrol.

I need to access the DropDownList in a Page_Load and a Repeater ItemDataBound event on the same page.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(...) Handles Me.Load
    x = ddl.SelectedValue 
End Sub

Protected Sub repeater_ItemDataBound(...) Handles repeater.ItemDataBound
    x = ddl.SelectedValue
End Sub
```

Assign the DropDownList to a variable e.g.

```
Dim ddl As Dropdownlist = Ctype(UserControl.FindControl("ddl"), Dropdownlist)
```

Doing this in the Page_Load event it's not then seen from inside the repeater. So do i just declare the variable in both or is there a better way of having it accessed by all events?

Comment: You need to assign the dropdownlist in both events.

Comment: Suggestion: I would add an internal or public method to the user control that returns the selected value of the dropdownlist. So you don't need to use findcontrol, just call this method.